# Criar uma chave flexibilizada para merge no R

Tags: r, merge, chave-primária

Preciso realizar um merge entre duas bases de dados mas, em função de inúmeros erros de digitação, gostaria de flexibilizar os critérios desse merge de modo que nos casos em que as chaves se difiram em apenas um caracter e que haja uma única correspondência entre as chaves 1 e 2, o merge ainda seja realizado.
Por exemplo, nos dataframes a seguir, esperava que as chaves **A**A_DLA_25051946 e **B**A_DLA_25051946 ainda resultassem em um merge entre os dataframes.

```
Teste$Chave1<-c("AA_DLA_25051946","BAJ_FRR_10091975","CBR_ARM_30111961")
Teste2$Chave2<-c("BA_DLA_25051946","AB_FB_31101952","ABR_ARM_30111961")
```

Criei uma função de comparação que parece funcionar, mas não consigo aplicá-la no merge:

```
comparar_strings <- function(coluna1, coluna2) {
  # Inicializa um vetor de resultados
  resultados <- logical(length = length(coluna1))
  
  # Loop pelos elementos das colunas
  for (i in seq_along(coluna1)) {
    str1 <- coluna1[i]
    str2 <- coluna2[i]
    
    # Comparar se as strings sÃ£o idÃªnticas ou diferem por apenas um caractere
    resultados[i] <- sum(strsplit(str1, "")[[1]] != strsplit(str2, "")[[1]]) <= 1
  }
  
  # Retorna vetor de resultados
  return(resultados)
}
```

Comment: Duas perguntas: 1) As colunas têm o mesmo tamanho? 2) Para cada elemento de `coluna1` quer só um elemento de `coluna2` (caso exista) ou quer todos que estejam a uma distância máxima igual a 1?

Comment: As colunas não tem o mesmo tamanho. Gostaria que o merge fosse realizado apenas nos casos em que haja uma única correspondência. Nos casos em que houver mais de uma correspondência, gostaria que retornasse NA. @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não é necessária tanta ginástica com `strsplit`, aqui está uma solução em R base com `nchar` e, sobretudo, `agrep`.
A função `comparar_strings` chma uma função interna `f` que faz o trabalho todo. Se as strings tiverem o mesmo número de caracteres, usa o `agrep` com um máximo de uma substituição para encontrar correspondências em `coluna2`. Depois é só verificar se houve correspondências e ficar com a primeira.

Nota que o máximo de substituições é dado por um argumento extra, `cost`.

```r
comparar_strings <- function(coluna1, coluna2, cost) {
  f <- function(x, y, cost) {
    resultados <- sapply(y, \(.y) {
      out <- if(nchar(.y) == nchar(x)) {
        agrep(x, .y, max.distance = cost, fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE)
      } else NA_character_
      is.na(out) <- length(out) == 0L
      out
    }) |> na.omit()
    resultados[1L]
  }
  sapply(coluna1, f, y = coluna2, cost = cost)
}

Teste <- data.frame(Chave1 = c("AA_DLA_25051946","BAJ_FRR_10091975","CBR_ARM_30111961"))
Teste2 <- data.frame(Chave2 = c("BA_DLA_25051946","AB_FB_31101952","ABR_ARM_30111961"))

cost_vec <- list(substitutions = 1L)
comparar_strings(Teste$Chave1, Teste2$Chave2, cost = cost_vec)
#>   AA_DLA_25051946.BA_DLA_25051946               BAJ_FRR_10091975.NA 
#>                 "BA_DLA_25051946"                                NA 
#> CBR_ARM_30111961.ABR_ARM_30111961 
#>                "ABR_ARM_30111961"

Teste$resultado <- comparar_strings(Teste$Chave1, Teste2$Chave2, cost = cost_vec)
Teste
#>             Chave1        resultado
#> 1  AA_DLA_25051946  BA_DLA_25051946
#> 2 BAJ_FRR_10091975             <NA>
#> 3 CBR_ARM_30111961 ABR_ARM_30111961
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Testei com uma amostra da minha base e de fato sua solução rodou. Estou tentando implementá-la para minha base completa mas, por enquanto, sem sucesso em função do tempo de execução. De todo modo, já ajudou muito. @RuiBarradas

Comment: @BrunaFirmino Quanto ao tempo de execução eu sugeria usar a minha função Rcpp da resposta à outra pergunta mas a pergunta foi apagada. A função resolve o problema e é mais de 100x mais rápida.